# Javascript output sent to PHP for adding into database

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have wrote a HTML/Javascript code generator but instead of outputting the code to a HTML site i would like the code to be send to php to be added to a database but i cant work out how to get the out put of the javascript into PHP

there is also another javascript doc to go with this if you need it to make it work ..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<script src="../voucher_codes.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<h1>pattern codes</h1>
<ul id="pattern-codes"></ul>



<script>


    var patternCodes = voucher_codes.generate({
prefix: "BREAK-",
postfix: "-2019",
        length:5,
        count: 5,
        charset: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"



    });

    function fillList(listId, items) {
        var list = document.getElementById(listId);
        items.forEach(function(item) {
            list.innerHTML += "<li>" + item + "</li>";
        });
    }


    fillList("pattern-codes", patternCodes);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

i am wanting the output of the function "fillList" to send the output to PHP if this is possible....

Comment: Check Ajax, http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ and https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

Comment: I agree with @Michael

Comment: can someone give me a pointer to what part i should be looking at with ajax never heard of it ?

Comment: Please understand that if you generate voucher code on the client side you are vulnerable to get them stolen or modified. As a general rule you should never trust the client. If you need something to remain secret, do not let the client handle it. At best it could mean to lose track of your voucher and at worst to get yourself pawn by code injection.

Comment: i was going to make the client side then put them into a sql database server side?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to look into using AJAX or the Axios library to send requests to a server page such as PHP.

Here is a simple AJAX POST server request in Javascript:

`

```
<script>
    function loadDoc() {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          var response = this.responseText;
         }
      };
      xhttp.open("POST", "request_page.php", true); // set method and page
      xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); // set content type that we are sending POST data
      xhttp.send("key=VALUE&key=VALUE"); // POST values
}
</script>
```

`

On the PHP page if you want to give a response of data to use back in Javascript, make sure to
 `json_encode($array_values)`

the data array before echoing it out and set the headers to

`header("Content-Type: application/json")`

so you can grab the response data in Javascript and it can be turned into a Javascript {Object} or [Array]

Comment: looking at this i found this im going to try this as it might be what im after